# Accessing private members of the superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, private

I have two classes, class A and class B which extends class A.
We say that you cannot access private members of the superclass. Let's say that class A has a public method which returns the private member. Now, if we create an instance of class B and call that method, we can actually see that it could access the private member. Why does this happen?

Comment: cause the getters/setters are made for that, they make you handel the private variables of any class

Answer (score 4):

Still you are accessing it's public member (method), no matter what it's internal implementation. You cannot access private members directly, that is what it mean.

Answer (score 1):

Class A has access to the private variable, and class B has access to the getX method. When you call A.getX(), class A passes on the value of x. Think of it like a proxy. You don't have access to that object, but you can route your request through something that does.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the getter method to class `A` you have changed the contract exposed by `A` to allow all other classes read-only access that member.  Having only a getter does not allow anybody else (including the subclass) to *modify* the private member, only read it.

There's no particular reason a subclass should be limited in a way that other classes are not.

Answer (score 0):

The private public protected and default modifiers define on which scope a component is accessible, getX() is defined in the scope of class A, for which x is defined private hence it can access x.